# Selecting active option in jQuery Mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

The mobile page for my app has a header with a jQuery Mobile dropdown select menu list like below.

```
<span data-role="fieldcontain" id="category-dropdown">
  <select name="select-native-2" id="select-native-2" data-mini="true">
    <option value="<%= root_path %>">Home</option>
    <option value="<%= newest_path %>">New</option>    
    <option value="<%= group_path(Group.find(1)) %>">Group 1</option>
    <option value="<%= group_path(Group.find(2)) %>">Group 2</option>
    <option value="<%= group_path(Group.find(3)) %>">Group 3</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

I'm using the Javascript below to navigate to the page that is selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#select-native-2").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val()!='') {
      window.location.href=$(this).val();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

My problem is, when a user redirects to another page, the select menu defaults back to the first option ("Home"). How can I make the select menu reflect the current page?

My guess is that I need to

**#1 mark which option is "active,"** then

**#2 make sure that is activated on the selectmenu via javascript**.

What's the best way to do those two things?

I can do **#1** as below, but it's quite ugly

```
<option value="<%= root_path %>" id="<%= "active" if params[:controller] == "links" && params[:action] == "index" %>">
```

As for **#2,** I'm not sure what the best way is to select it.

Would appreciate your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the `selected` attribute?

```
<span data-role="fieldcontain" id="category-dropdown">
  <select name="select-native-2" id="select-native-2" data-mini="true">
    <option value="<%= root_path %>">Home</option>
    <option value="<%= newest_path %>">New</option>    
    <option selected value="<%= group_path(Group.find(1)) %>">Group 1</option>
    <option value="<%= group_path(Group.find(2)) %>">Group 2</option>
    <option value="<%= group_path(Group.find(3)) %>">Group 3</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

This would make "Group 1" the selected option on page load. You would just have to figure out which option will get this attribute.  But that should be easy to do on the Ruby side.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, this is perfect. Can you expand on a good way to do this via ruby? I'm thinking an if/else between `value` and `selected value` would be very messy. Is there a neater way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Steve's solution, I wrote a helper to help select the current page.

```
def is_selected?(action, name)
  if params[:controller] == "links" # this is the controller for my root and newest paths
    "selected" if params[:action] == action
  elsif params[:controller] == "groups"
    "selected" if @group.name == name
  end
end
```